# What will trigger Expiry date workflow?

Tags: 2010

I want to create a workflow that will be triggered if Expiry date equals to Today.

But it doesn't seem to work[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a retention policy, that's exactly what they're designed to do.
You can create a retention policy for either a list/library or a content type (which would then affect all items of that content type in any list/library). For the retention policy, you set the criteria, such as modified date + 2 years, or Expiration Date + 0 years, and then an action. The action could be things like delete the item or run a workflow.

You can find these settings by going to the library settings and selecting Information Management Policy Settings.

For more info:
https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/sharepoint-retention-policies/

Comment: Hi Mike, I have seen your link, but I'm not sure as to how it will help me in my solution. I just need a simple workflow that will notify the intended users if the password is about to expire based on the future date , that is predefined on the list

Comment: Did I misunderstand? You have a list that has a date field called "Expiry date". And, you want a workflow to run on that date for each list item? You can either 1) run a workflow when the item is added to the list and wait for the expiry date, or 2) use a retention policy which will run the workflow after the expiry date passes.

Comment: Thanks Mike ,I have used the 1st option .... still waiting to see if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I often use:

- Install the free HarePoint Workflow Scheduler
- create a view that shows all items where Expiry Date = [Today]
- Use HarePoint Workflow Scheduler to run the workflow once a day on all items in that view.

Comment: Hi teylyn please note that i'm using SPD 2010, I dnt have access to the actual server.